# Error after reorganization modulaire

Tags: c++, class, linker-errors

I transformed my program in a modular program becahse all was in one header. 
But now there is a problem I don't know ..

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"Vehicule::createVehicule(std::string)", referenced from:
   _main in main-aV2PNG.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Vehicule.h"

int main()
{
Vehicule *v=Vehicule::createVehicule("fr");
presenter(v);
return 0;
}
```

vehicule.h

```
#include <iostream>

class Vehicule
{
public:
virtual std::string getMarque() const =0;
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o,const Vehicule *v);
static Vehicule* createVehicule(std::string origine);
};

void presenter(const Vehicule *v)
{
std::cout << "Vehicule " << v << std::endl;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o,const Vehicule *v)
{
return o << v->getMarque();
}
```

vehicule.cpp

```
#include "Vehicule.h"
#include "CreateurConcretRenault.h"
#include "CreateurConcretFiat.h"

Vehicule* Vehicule::createVehicule(std::string origine)
{
if(origine=="fr") return new CreateurConcretRenault();
else if(origine=="ita") return new CreateurConcretFiat();

else return new CreateurConcretRenault();
}
```

CreateurConcretRenault.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Vehicule.h"

class CreateurConcretRenault : public Vehicule
{
public:
std::string getMarque() const;
};
```

CreateurConcretRenault.cpp

```
#include "CreateurConcretRenault.h"

std::string CreateurConcretRenault::getMarque() const
{
return "Renault";
}
```

CreateurConcretFiat.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Vehicule.h"

class CreateurConcretFiat : public Vehicule
{
public:
std::string getMarque() const;
};
```

CreateurConcretFiat.cpp

```
#include "CreateurConcretFiat.h"

std::string CreateurConcretFiat::getMarque() const
{
return "Fiat";
}
```

Comment: French identifiers for the win! Just to make sure that non-francophone readers won't get an idea what your code is doing...!

Comment: What is your linker command? It looks like you are not linking in the object file for vehicule.cpp.

Comment: I use XCode..Perhaps the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `std::string`, but you never included `<string>`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to put all in one header and it works ..

So I thought i forgot something